# SQL: SyntaxError: order by with row_number() function

Tags: sql, row-number, sql-order-by

I have the following table `Employee`:

```
+----+--------+
| Id | Salary |
+----+--------+
| 1  | 150    |
| 2  | 290    |
| 3  | 302    |
+----+--------+
```

I am using the following code to find the second highest salary:

```
with t as 
(
    select 
        Salary, 
        row_number() over (order by Salary desc) as salary_ord 
    from 
        Employee
)
select Salary 
from t 
where salary_ord == 2
```

However, I get an error:

> SyntaxError: near 't as (
>          select Salary, row_number() over (order by Salary desc) as salary_ord'

What did I do wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL, the correct comparison operator is `=`, not `==`.  So, this is the ANSI SQL version of your query:

```
with t as (
      select Salary, row_number() over (order by Salary desc) as salary_ord 
      from Employee
     )
select Salary
from t
where salary_ord = 2;
```

However, your error suggests that your database doesn't support `with` or window functions.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server,

You can do:

```
select top 1 Salary 
from Employee 
order by Salary desc
offset 1 row fetch next 1 row only
```